# Quartus II: Pin incompatible with a bank it is not on

Tags: fpga, cyclone, quartus

I am using the pin planner of Quartus II to place my I/O signals on my Cyclone IV pins. I am stuck on the following fitter error:

> Error (169029): Pin adc0_in[0] is incompatible with I/O bank 3.  Pin
>   uses I/O standard LVDS, which has a VCCIO requirement incompatible
>   with that bank's VCCIO setting or its other pins that use VCCIO 3.3V.

The Cyclone IV is organised in banks that should have the same VCCIO. The strange thing about this error message is that the pin `adc0_in[0]` has been placed on bank 8, *not* bank 3, so there should not be any contention. (Figure 6-10 from [the datasheet](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/cyclone-iv/cyiv-51006.pdf) shows that bank 8 and bank 3 use `VCCIO8` and `VCCIO3` respectively.)

I am also getting the error

> Error (171169): Previous compilation results are reused as part of
>   this compilation and may cause the error on this compilation.

but I have made sure that incremental compilation is not enabled (as suggested [here](http://quartushelp.altera.com/11.1/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/efitcc_fitcc_iwap_fit_failed.htm)) and that the database folders have been deleted (as suggested [here](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=37599)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be that the configuration device (a Max II) had pins on both bank 3 and bank 8, and was implicitly enforcing the restriction that bank 3 and bank 8 must have the same VCCIO. This was fixed by going to

`Settings` > `Device` > `Device and Pin Options...` > `Configuration` > `Configuration device`

and unchecking the box "Force VCCIO to be compatible with configuration I/O voltage".